# How to send multiple emails in PHP and MySQL via phpmailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I have a problem. When i click send button, just `zxc@hotmail.com` receives the message.

How to change it? I'm use Gmail SMTP send out.

There are 2 records in the database:

Here is my code:

```
include "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$db = "mailTest";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$query = "SELECT email FROM list";

$recordset = mysql_query($query);
$row_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset);
$tota_row_recordset = mysql_num_rows($recordset);
$msg = strip_tags($_POST['msg']);
$mail= new PHPMailer(); //建立新物件 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
{
    $to = $row['email'];
    $mail->AddAddress($to, "Test Message"); 
}      
$mail->IsSMTP();    
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";     
$mail->Port = 465;      
$mail->CharSet = "big5";
$mail->Subject = "Test Message";     
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx";    
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx";   
$mail->Body = "$msg";
$mail->IsHTML(true);           
if(!$mail->Send()) {      
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;       
} else {      
header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this loop you overwrite the recipient with each iteration, so only the last one stays to receive the email:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
{
    $to = $row['email'];
}
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Change your code to

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create object FIRST
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
{
    $to = $row['email'];
    $mail->AddAddress($to, "Test Message"); // add each DB entry to list of recipients
}
```

Comment: when i put $mail->AddAddress($to, "Test Message"); the webpage will show the error.

Comment: @tommychoo changed example to fix this, try again

Comment: @tommychoo just replace the full part listed the top with the full example at the bottom

Comment: Sorry, the problem still exist.. I changed the code at the top. then, how to change again ?

Comment: @tommychoo edit your question to reflect the change and post the actual error message you receive.

Comment: OK, Let's look the top i changed, but abc@gmail.com still not received

Comment: Thanks, the program is work now! but the emails was received and store in important box. How to change it in the inbox received

Comment: You can't choose where it goes - that's up to the user and their filters.

Answer (score 3):

try this below:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
{
    $to = $row['email'];
    $mail= new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->CharSet = "big5";

    $mail->Subject = "Test Message";

    $mail->Username = "xxxxxx";

    $mail->Password = "xxxxxx";

    $mail->Body = "$msg";

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->AddAddress($to, "Test Message");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {

    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't really be instantiating a new PHPMailer on every cycle!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['sbmit']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['email_address']);$i++)
    {

          $to = $_POST['email_address'][$i];
          echo $to."<br />";
          $subject = 'Thank you for Subscribing';
          $message = $_POST['news'];
          $headers = 'From: dhakalneil@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
          'Reply-To: xyz@hotmail.com' . "\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


         echo $_POST['email_address'][$i]."<br />";
         ini_set("SMTP","smtp.ntc.net.np" );
         ini_set('sendmail_from', 'dhakalneil@gmail.com');
         if( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
         {
                echo "Mail has been sent to admin<br />";
         }
         else
         {
                echo "Mail could not been sent";
         } 

    }
}


?>
```